# Using Data Import Wizard to Update Existing Accounts without any Contacts

Tags: data-import-wizard

I'm trying to update existing account records (that are not associated with contacts), and in the Update Existing Records section, it's requiring that I select something for "Match Contact By" - I don't have the option to leave it as "--None--". Even if I select something (I've tried Salesforce.com ID and name) leave that field unmapped, I repeatedly get a report back that says all rows of my csv were ignored. I can only assume that they're being ignored because of the contact issue. I've updated account information via DIW before, so I'm not sure what's going on this time. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hi Jill

You say you're trying to update existing Accounts, what option are you selecting for matching the accounts? Salesforce Id or Name & Site?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Apologies that my question was unclear. I was running into an issue where my Account updates kept being ignored. I thought it was because the DIW was requiring me to choose a field for Contacts when I don't have any contact fields in my CSV file (yellow). But it turns out it was because I didn't check this box (pink) to allow it to update existing Accounts.

Answer (score 0):

SF Support helped me figure out that it was not about the Contacts field (yellow), it's about checking the box re updating existing accounts (pink). [image]